# How to implement Caching while loading SWCs dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, caching, flashdevelop, swc

I'm loading dynamic loading of all my SWCs in my master SWF, in order to load master swf faster, however now I need to cache all my swcs in local machine to speed up things.

```
private function loadAssets():void 
    {   
        swcObj=new Object();
        swcObj.swcPath='assets/swc/1.swc';
        swcObj.className="Part_0_1";
        swcs.push(swcObj);

        swcObj=new Object();
        swcObj.swcPath='assets/swc/2.swc';
        swcObj.className="0_2";
        swcs.push(swcObj);

        swcObj=new Object();
        swcObj.swcPath='assets/swc/3.swc';
        swcObj.className="0_3";
        swcs.push(swcObj);
    }
```

Then I'm using this array to use all the classes in my project, but I have no idea how to cache these swcs for faster use, if anyone have idea, please share.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the browser does this pre-caching for you, you don't need to produce extra efforts. So, just load them normally and don't worry about caching. You can, however, motivate the user to increase their local browser cache in order to potentially lessen time spent on waiting while your assets are loaded, but this won't help should the user watch three tons of YouTube each day.

Answer (score 0):

SWC files are not intended for dynamic loading.
They are static libraries that can be linked in a swf using
`-include-libraries` and `library-path` options of mxmlc or - since you seem to be using FlashDevelop - `SWC Include Libraries` and `SWC Libraries` in `Project>Compiler options`
. SWC's may hold code (classes), assets (symbols/bitmaps/sounds...) or combination of the two.

Loading assets dynamically is done through flash.display.Loader
you may use the Loader as a simple DisplayObject instance that you add on stage:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary

, or use its ApplicationDomain as a library of Class definitions that will allow you to create instances at will :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#includeExamplesSummary

Caching from the browser will be sufficient in most cases, unless you have VERY specific needs

In the end, there is different ways to optimize loading times, one of which is having a small swf acting as loader/home menu, and loading rest of the content on demand like you seem to try doing, but you can also create a single swf with several frames, which will be "streamed" by flash player, example:
1st frame as small as possible holding just a few kb for a splash screen/logo/loading/whatever you want, to make the initial blank screen as short as possible, then second frame holding the main content. You can event extent this system with for instance

- two levels of preloader: a first tiny frame with just a logo, second one with progress bar, and full background  if needed
- split content like home screen/menus in a frame, gameplay in the another, if you are making a game, so that gameplay continues loading while you are already displaying the menu